# Xamarin SQLIteConnection: method "Get" throw exception if key doesn't exist

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

When I try run this code:

```
var l=_sqliteconnection.Get<Preferences> (x=>x.Key=="Login");
```

I have got exception, because entity in table "Preferences" with key "Login" doesn't exist, but if entity exist, it's ok.
I can use try/catch blocks, but can I do it without try and catch?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the exception message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `Get<TClass>` class documentation on returns:

> The object that matches the given predicate. Throws a not found exception if the object is not found

If you don't want the exception it's better to use `Find<TClass>` that get the object with the given primary key or null if the object is not found.